# Unknown column 'a9162e80e079a0051c8b7f88195a94da' in 'field list' (encrypted password)

Tags: php, mysql, passwords, registration, password-encryption

I have checked and tried to change my code but still, the same error and I have tried to solve this problem for about 2 days, every day about 2-3 hours of thinking and changing.

Im quite new to this and cant find the line where the error is.
i have looked into this problem here but still cant find an answer. tried to add '' still nothing and my mysql table exists too, im sure of it.

need some help.

```
if(isset($_POST["register"])){
    $username = protect($_POST['username']);
    $password = protect($_POST['password']);
    $email = protect($_POST['email']);

    if(strlen($username) > 20){
        echo "Username must be less than 20 characters!";
    }elseif(strlen($email) > 100){
        echo "E-mail must be less than 100 characters!";
    }elseif(strlen($username) < 4){
        echo "Username must be more than 4 characters!";
    }elseif(strlen($password) < 4){
        echo "Password must be more than 4 characters!";
    }else{
        $register1 = @mysql_query("SELECT id FROM user WHERE username = '$username' ") or die(@mysql_error());
        $register2 = @mysql_query("SELECT id FROM user WHERE email = '$email' ") or die(@mysql_error());
        if(@mysql_num_rows($register1) > 0){
            echo "That username is already in use!";
        }elseif(mysql_num_rows($register2) > 0){
            echo "That e-mail address is already in use!";
        }else{
            $ins1 = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO stats (gold, attack, defense, food) VALUES (100,10,10,100)") or die(mysql_error());
            $ins2 = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO unit (worker, farmer, warrior, defender, archer, longbowmen, phalanxmen, knight, cavalary) VALUES (5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)") or die(mysql_error());
            $ins3 = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (username, password, email) VALUES('$_POST[$username]', ".md5('$_POST[$password]')." ,'$_POST[$email]')") or die(mysql_error());
            $ins4 = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO weapon(sword, shield, bow, longbow, towershield, longsword, pike, horse) VALUES (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)") or die(mysql_error());
            $ins5 = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO ranking (attack, defense, overall) VALUES (0,0,0)");
                echo("Congratulations, You have registered!");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `"cant find the line where the error is"` Remove all those nasty error suppression symbols (`@`)

Comment: and of course the usual rant about using deprecated methods. Use mysqli/pdo instead, secure everything against sql injections

Comment: And please have a look at the [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function, the MD5 algorithm is not appropriate to hash passwords, because it is ways too fast ([8 Giga hashes](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/#performance) per second with common hardware).

Answer (score 1):

Use '' to surround your password value, otherwise mysql interprets the text as name of a column instead the value:

```
    $ins3 = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (username, password, email) VALUES('$_POST[$username]', '".md5('$_POST[$password]')."' ,'$_POST[$email]')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `".md5('$_POST[$password]')."` with `'".md5('$_POST[$password]')."'` (added quotes)